# How to get the tags of posts in draft?

Tags: php, wordpress, tags

I'm using get_tags in a dropdown to get the tags of the posts in my wordpress blog. It doesn't list the tags for posts that are in draft. But I want to show does tags, and only does. Anybody an idea how to do this?

Code looks like this at this point:

```
        <?php

            $ts_tags = get_tags();
            foreach($ts_tags as $ts_tag) {
                echo '<option value="'.$ts_tag->slug.'" '.selected($ts_tag->slug, $search_get['tag']).'>'.$ts_tag->name.'</option>';
            }
        ?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a custom query to select both postes and drafts and get the tags by yourself. It's not that hard to do, use Wordpress documentation. Good luck.

Comment: I could be wrong, but it seems that it isn't as simple as that, i tried what you suggest, but then i just get all the tags per post, and you get the tags double, not one time that links to all the other posts. It could be that I'm overlooking something, but I don't think so. Thanks for the superfriendly answer, thought. Cheers!